# Creating a Heatmap with Median values in R

Tags: r

I am quite a newbie to programming in R, so my apologies for any seemingly redundant questions before hand.

My current data matrix has about 2000ish rows of individuals observations and 93 columns of which the 1st column is a factor variable (8 levels) and the following 92 columns are continuous variables.

I want to create a heatmap with on the X-axis the 8 levels from the factor variable (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) and on the Y axis the 92 continuous variables with their mean values per level of the factor variable. The 92 continuous variables have readily been z-standardized. Can anybody provide me with some tips to start? Thank you.

Best,

Jasper

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to make heatmap plots in R, but the most straight forward in my opinion is ggplots. Take a look at https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/.